# Setting up SLIME on MacOSX

Tags: macos, emacs, installation, slime, sbcl

I've been dancing around LISP for decades, but now have decided to get serious. I'm going through the online version of Practical Common LISP.

This is my setup:

MacOSX 10.7.8
Xcode 4.5.2
SBCL 1.0.55.0-abb03f9
Emacs 24.2.1  (x86_64-apple-darwin, NS apple-appkit-1038.36)
SLIME 1.6

I tried to follow the instructions listed in the link:

http://emacs-sbcl-slime.blogspot.com/2010/11/sbcl-emacs-slime-macosx.html

…but the problem is that on the MacOSX platform, nothing seems to be located where it should.

SBCL was installed using its own script…it is working.

I setup the SBCL_HOME env var as instructed.

Emacs was installed by dmg from this link:

http://emacs-sbcl-slime.blogspot.com/2010/11/sbcl-emacs-slime-macosx.html

…and is running.

SLIME, however (which was download via cvs to ˜/.emacs.d/slime) doesn't appear to be recognized. I can't get the "CL-USER>" prompt described by the author.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think you should post your errors so that people can help you dig into it. I also new to lisp/elisp, and after taking a look on the url you provided, I use its [basic set up](https://gist.github.com/4259209) (with a bit modification, remove the paredit part) and it works on my Ubuntu. Or you can see my personal basic [configuration](https://github.com/ispinfx/.emacs.d/blob/master/init/init-slime.el).

Comment: Even though it's for Linux, with -- I think -- minor changes, you should be able to follow [this guide](http://www.mohiji.org/2011/01/modern-common-lisp-on-linux/) because it uses [Quicklisp](http://www.quicklisp.org) instead of CVS to fetch SLIME.

Comment: I wiped emacs/slime, loaded/configured quicklisp in sbcl'

Comment: ...and took a breather. I then setup an editor from the App Store that has simple lisp syntax highlighting.

Comment: I suspected that quicklisp could load slime...if I decide to go back to slime that's how I'll do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Copy the entire directory of slime to `emacs/site-lisp`
2. Ensure your lisp is accesible from the terminal. Just type `sbcl` in Terminal. Lisp interpreter should start.
3. put into your .emacs file something like `(setq inferior-lisp-program "sbcl")`

It should work then.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest just getting [Emacs Prelude](https://github.com/bbatsov/prelude), which ships with a good Common Lisp + SLIME configuration be default. It's preconfigured for Clozure CL on OSX (given that it's arguably the most popular Common Lisp distribution on OSX), but a simple line of Emacs Lisp in your Prelude personal config can switch SLIME's default Lisp to SBCL:

```
(setq slime-default-lisp 'sbcl)
```

The best way to install SLIME itself is probably via the [Quicklisp's SLIME helper](http://www.quicklisp.org/beta/).

Comment: Browsing the sample code on the Clozure site I can see why. Can I use a lib like CAPI in sbcl or can I use Clozure's GUI libs under sbcl?

Comment: Unfortunately - no. They are not portable.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using the excellent LispBox bundle that takes care of all the setup for you? It's super easy: http://common-lisp.net/project/lispbox/

It includes emacs, SLIME, the Clozure Common Lisp environment, QuickLisp and everything preconfigured.